# How best to synchronize memory access shared between kernel and user space, in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, synchronization, spinlock

I can't find any function to acquire spinlock in Win32 Apis.
Is there a reason?

When I need to use spinlock, what do I do?

I know there is an CriticalSectionAndSpinCount function.
But that's not what I want.

Edit:
I want to synchronize a memory which will be shared between kernel space and user space. -The memory will be mapped.
I should lock it when I access the data structure and the locking time will be very short.
The data structure(suppose it is a queue) manages event handles to interaction each other.
What synchronization mechanism should I use?

Comment: Well "Ke" means it's a kernel mode API; this API is doubtless used by the user-mode synchronization APIs. What specifically are you trying to accomplish that the CriticalSection APIs aren't providing?

Comment: Can you explain why the Win32 API you named is not what you want?

Comment: Because the function will sleep, if it exhausts all given spin counts.

Comment: It modifies IRQL, no way that's possible in user mode.

Comment: @Benjamin - you might want to change the title as well - the rephrased new q is much more likely to get specific solutions if you do :-)

Comment: I've edited the title to better fit the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 4):

A spinlock is clearly not appropriate for  user-level synchronization. From http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/locks.mspx:

> All types of spin locks raise the IRQL
>   to DISPATCH_LEVEL or higher. Spin
>   locks are the only synchronization
>   mechanism that can be used at IRQL >=
>   DISPATCH_LEVEL. Code that holds a spin
>   lock runs at IRQL >= DISPATCH_LEVEL,
>   which means that the system’s thread
>   switching code (the dispatcher) cannot
>   run and, therefore, the current thread
>   cannot be pre-empted.

Imagine if it were possible to take a spin lock in user mode:  Suddenly the thread would not be able to be pre-empted.  So on a single-cpu machine, this is now an exclusive and real-time thread.  The user-mode code would now be responsible for handling interrupts and other kernel-level tasks.  The code could no longer access any paged memory, which means that the user-mode code would need to know what memory is currently paged and act accordingly.  Cats and dogs living together, mass hysteria!

Perhaps a better question would be to tell us what you are trying to accomplish, and ask what synchronization method would be most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a managed user-mode `SpinLock` [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx).  Handle with care, as advised in the docs - it's easy to go badly wrong with these locks.

The only way to access this in native code is via the Win32 API you named already - `CriticalSectionAndSpinCount` and its siblings.